# How do I create several commands with scriptine?

Tags: python, scriptine

I have some code and I would like to use scriptine to create several commands for a single script.  Here's my code so far:

```
from scriptine import run, path, log
import sys

import mymodule1 as m1
import mymodule2 as m2

def load_command():
    '''
    Load something
    '''
    m1.main()

def exec_command():
    '''
    Exec something
    '''
    m2.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

But when i run it, nothing happens.  I cannot figure out what I'm missing.  I've tested both main()  functions inside each module and they're OK.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me.

If you're running on Linux, I would add the first line to the .py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

And then make it executable:

```
> chmod +x myfile.py
```

Then you can run your command like this:

```
> ./myfile.py load
> ./myfile.py exec
```

Otherwise, you can run your command like this:

```
> python myfile.py load
> python myfile.py exec
```